# How to use DLL in C Sharp

Tags: c#, c, dll

I want to extract ACPI tables in C# application.
There is Intel's open source code to work with ACPI and BIOS written in C.
Here is the [link](https://www.acpica.org/).
I suppose I can build DLL from C code and then use it in C sharp.
But I'm confused, because I don't know how to do it.

Is there a good article or guide or starting point for my case?

Comment: Your starting place should, as always, be to search. There are tons of resources about that on the web and on this very site.

Comment: I can build DLL. I'm asking how to use it in C#

Comment: Well then look just at the right sidebar "related" links.

Comment: Oh, never seen it before! Thank you

Comment: That's the list you also got while entering your question (give or take).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may start with the [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).